# How to start a new activity for putting facebook logout button?

Tags: android, android-activity, facebook-login

I'm new in Android programming and I don't know how I can put the facebook logout botton in another activity (called whatToDo) considering that the login botton is in the LoginActivity.

This is the initial code of Facebook tutorial to implement Facebook login, but from this code I don't know how to implement what I want.

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {
private CallbackManager callbackManager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
    callbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();
    TextView login_text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.fb_login);

    LoginButton fbLoginButton = (LoginButton) findViewById(R.id.fb_login_button);
    fbLoginButton.setReadPermissions("email");
    fbLoginButton.registerCallback(callbackManager, new FacebookCallback<LoginResult>() {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(LoginResult loginResult) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(LoginActivity.this, whatToDo.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Logged!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onCancel() {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Cancel Event!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        @Override
        public void onError(FacebookException exception) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), exception.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    callbackManager.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}
```

}

What extra code do I have to insert in LoginActivity and whatToDo activity?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is no logout button from `Facebook`. You can put your own button and try to logout the user if he/she is logged in on the click of that button.

Comment: You've registered callback to `LoginButton`. If you want to perform a login you have to write `LoginManager.getInstance().logInWithReadPermissions(this, Arrays.asList("public_profile"));` This [link](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/android) can help.